# Unity C# - Instantiating a game Object for a hex grid is giving me the error Cannot convert from CustomClass to UnityEngine.Object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts one that generate's a hex map and the other that provides the name and prefab. Within my MapGen script im getting the error

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'NodeType' to 'UnityEngine.Object'
>   (CS1503) (Assembly-CSharp)

Here's the code of the first script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class NodeMng : MonoBehaviour {


    public int height; 
    public int width;
    private float MapSizeY;
    private float MapSizeX;


    public GameObject selectedUnit; 
    public GameObject[] hexGridTiles;
    public NodeType[] nodeTypes;



    void Start () 
    {
        mapGeneration();
    }

    public void mapGeneration (){


        for (MapSizeY = 0; MapSizeY < height; MapSizeY = MapSizeY + 0.88f)
        {
            bool doOffset = false; 
            for(MapSizeX = 0; MapSizeX < width; MapSizeX = MapSizeX + 0.769f )
            {
                float offset = doOffset ? 0.451f : 0f; 
                MapSizeY = MapSizeY + offset; 
                Vector3 spawnPoint = new Vector3(MapSizeX, MapSizeY, 0); 


                var groundNode = (GameObject)Instantiate (nodeTypes [Random.Range (0, nodeTypes.Length)], spawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);


                groundNode.name = "Hex_" + MapSizeX + "_" + MapSizeY; 
                groundNode.transform.SetParent(transform, true); 
                ClickableTile ct = groundNode.GetComponent<ClickableTile>(); 
                ct.tileX = MapSizeX;
                ct.tileY = MapSizeY;
                ct.map = this;

                MapSizeY = MapSizeY - offset;
                doOffset = !doOffset; //! sets to true
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And heres the code for the second script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class NodeType{

    public string name;
    public GameObject hexGridTiles;




}
```

The error is on the following line

```
var groundNode = (GameObject)Instantiate (nodeTypes [Random.Range (0, nodeTypes.Length)], spawnPoint, Quaternion.identity);
```

When I change nodeTypes to hexGridTiles it works perfectly fine but in this case I need it to attach a string Value to each prefab for path-finding down the line so I'm not sure what this error is trying to tell me any help is much appreciated.

For clarity here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about

[image]

Comment: Er...if your `NodeType` class doesn't inherit from [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html), you can't use it in `Object.Instantiate()`. And since you're trying to convert it to a `GameObject` afterwards, shouldn't the object you pass into `Instantiate()` also be of type `GameObject` (eg. A prefab)?

Comment: I'm afraid that I've lost you a bit - Your correct I failed to have NodeType Inherit correctly and fixed that which solved the error but within my inspector I can't add prefabs nor does my string appear properly.

Comment: no, I'm pretty sure your original setup was correct. instead of having `NodeType` inherit from `UnityEngine.Object` just instatiate `nodeTypes [Random.Range (0, nodeTypes.Length)].hexGridTiles`

Comment: Yeah that fixed it thank you for that. If you want post that as the answer and I'll put it as accepted otherwise I'll just answer it and quote you. Thanks!

Comment: @NikaKasradze Oh, that makes sense - I assumed he was trying to instantiate an object with the `NodeType` script attached to it, so I was approaching the problem with a different interpretation.

Comment: I can't convert it to an answer, so I guess you can just answer it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit to this answer goes to Nika Kasradze I'm just posting it here for finality.

Nodetype needed to be instantiated as

nodeTypes [Random.Range (0, nodeTypes.Length)].hexGridTiles